# Don't we have to load the database class in the first place before we use any objects or methods in that class in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Here is some code excerpted from Codeigniter's user guide about models. There's no explicit load of the databass class, in which the object *db*, method *get* in the code below have to be defined. I've checked the autoload file, there is no autoload of this specific class.

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {

    var $title   = '';
    var $content = '';
    var $date    = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_last_ten_entries()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function insert_entry()
    {
        $this->title   = $_POST['title']; // please read the below note
        $this->content = $_POST['content'];
        $this->date    = time();

        $this->db->insert('entries', $this);
    }

    function update_entry()
    {
        $this->title   = $_POST['title'];
        $this->content = $_POST['content'];
        $this->date    = time();

        $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say you have checked the autoload file, what do you mean? This excerpt looks like it is pulled directly off the User Guide page. I imagine they are assuming the use of autoload here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CodeIgniter documentation states two methods of loading the database library and connection:

[Database - User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

> **Automatically Connecting**
>
> The "auto connect" feature will load
>   and instantiate the database class
>   with every page load. To enable "auto
>   connecting", add the word database to
>   the library array, as indicated in the
>   following file:
>
> ```
> application/config/autoload.php
> ```
>
> **Manually Connecting**
>
> If only some of your pages require
>   database connectivity you can manually
>   connect to your database by adding
>   this line of code in any function
>   where it is needed, or in your class
>   constructor to make the database
>   available globally in that class.
>
> $this->load->database();

Also, when loading the model as referenced by jss:

> You can tell the model loading
>   function to auto-connect by passing
>   TRUE (boolean) via the third
>   parameter, and connectivity settings,
>   as defined in your database config
>   file will be used:
>
> $this->load->model('Model_name', '',
>   TRUE);

Comment: Thank you, Mister, for the answer, I think I understand this problem better now. But, there are still two follow-up questions I would like to ask: 1. Is the "auto connect" feature only responsible for loading the database library/class, not a specific database, right? 2. If we manually load a specific database(not the library!) the library will also be loaded automatically, am I correct?

Comment: 1. - The autoload will only load the default database configuration, not a specific database 2. - Yes, manually loading the database will also load the database library.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll to the bottom of the Models page in the user guide where you got that example you'll see the section labeled [Connecting to your Database](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#conn), the first thing it explains is:

> When a model is loaded it does **NOT** connect automatically to your database.

It then provides you with the three options for connecting that are available.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter automaticly load db class based on application/config/database.php

it does not need to in autoload section

more explonation is on 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: The application/config/database.php is used to store the database connection details. It is not responsible for the loading of the database library. Please read the documentation you have provided again. When the database library is loaded using application/config/autoload.php however, these configuration connection settings will be used automatically.